# How to write inner query that returns latest message for a given user?

Tags: mysql

I have some tables like this:

```
USERS TABLE:
| id | created | active | fname | lname |

MESSAGES TABLE:
| id | userId| active | date | content |
```

I am trying to return some user information, along with the most recently added message for a given user.
Below is the structure of the results that I am rying to achieve:

```
| userId | userCreated | latestMessageDate| latestMessageContent |
```

The following query returns the user information:

```
SELECT 
user.id, 
user.created
FROM user
WHERE user.active = 1
```

... But how do I now attach the date of the latest message, along with the actual latest message?

I believe using an inner query is one such approach, but how do you write such a query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, m.id, m.userID, m.datem, m.content
FROM USERS AS u
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, userID, date, content
            FROM MESSAGES
            WHERE active
            ORDER BY date DESC) AS m
ON u.id = m.userId
WHERE u.active
    # AND u.id = {$int_user_id}
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Users.id AS userId,
    Users.created AS userCreated,
    LatestMessage.LatestMessageDate,
    MESSAGES.content AS latestMessageContent 
FROM
    Users
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(date) AS LatestMessageDate,
            MESSAGES.userId
        FROM
            MESSAGES
        GROUP BY
            MESSAGES.userId
    ) AS LatestMessage
    ON Users.id=LatestMessage.userId
    LEFT JOIN MESSAGES
        ON LatestMessage.LatestMessageDate=MESSAGES.date
        AND LatestMessage.userId=MESSAGES.userId
```